# Trying to find out who has created Cloud Watch Alarms in my AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

In my AWS account,my team has created 300 alarms. Is there a possiblity to check who has created which alarm?

**Note: Cloud Trail feature has not been enabled**

Comment: If it was created in the last 7 days, you can check CloudTrail dashboard. Otherwise, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

AWS CloudTrail does exactly that, don't think there is another way to see that info. anyway do you have any code that create alarms?